# How to use multiple ngx-slick-carousel on same page in Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, carousel, slick.js

I'm using slick carousel on my page , but it gives me an error and do not show 2nd carousel.
**slider.component.ts**

```
<div *ngIf="mainSlider">
    <div class="main__slider">
        <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig">
            <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
                <div class="main__slide">
                    <div class="main__slide-inner">
                        <img class="main__slide-image" src="/assets/img/{{slide.img}}.svg" alt="">
                        <div class="main__slide-title">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                        </div>
                        <div class="main__slide-subtitle">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odit?
                        </div>
                        <div class="main__slide-button">
                            <div class="main__slide-hint">
                                <img src="assets/img/sandglass.svg" alt="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                                adipisicing elit. Deleniti esse atque eveniet incidunt.
                            </div>
                            <img src="assets/img/icons/dotted-arrow.svg" alt="">
                            <a class="button-blue" href="#">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ngx-slick-carousel>
    </div>
    <div class="main__slider-arrows">
        <button class="slick-arrow" (click)="prev()"><img src="assets/img/icons/arrow-slider.svg" alt=""></button>
        <button class="slick-arrow" style="transform: rotateY(180deg);" (click)="next()"><img
                src="assets/img/icons/arrow-slider.svg" alt=""></button>
    </div>
    <div class="main__slider-info">
        <div class="slider-index">
            <span class="current-slide">01</span>/<span class="num-slide">03</span>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-progress">
            <div class="slider-progress__back"></div>
            <span [style.width.%]="progressBarWidth"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="eventsSlider">
    <div class="news-slider-mobile">
        <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #eventsModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig">
            <div class="events-slider">
                <div class="events-slider__arrows news-arrows active-arrows"></div>
                <div class="events-slider__arrows activity-arrows"></div>
                <div class="events__tabs">
                    <div class="title tab news-tab active">
                        News
                    </div>
                    <div class="switch first-on">
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title tab activity-tab">
                        Events
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="events__tab-content">
                    <div class="news-item tab-item active-tab">
                        <div class="news-slider-mobile">
                            <a *ngFor="let banner of eventsBanners" href="#" class="events__item">
                                <div class="events__item-image">
                                    <img src="assets/img/{{ banner.img }}.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="events__item-wrapper">
                                    <div class="date-view">
                                        <div class="date-view__date">
                                            <img src="images/icons/calendar.svg" alt="">${{banner.date}}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="date-view__view">
                                            <img src="images/icons/eye.svg" alt="">${{banner.views}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="events__item-title">
                                    ${{banner.title}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="events__item-text">
                                    ${{banner.description}}
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ngx-slick-carousel>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have `mainSlider` and `eventsSlider` , also I tried to give personal `#slickModal` names (@ViewChild also watching own modal) to each slick carousel.
**slider.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SlickCarouselComponent } from 'ngx-slick-carousel';

import { eventsBanners } from './banners';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.scss']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() mainSlider: boolean;
  @Input() eventsSlider: boolean;

  @ViewChild('slickModal') slickModal: SlickCarouselComponent;
  @ViewChild('eventsModal') eventsModal: SlickCarouselComponent;
...
```

I import app-slider on main page
**main-page.component.html**

```
<section class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main__inner">
            <app-slider mainSlider="true"></app-slider>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="events">
    <div class="container">
        <app-slider eventsSlider="true"></app-slider>
    </div>
</section>
```

On first banner I'm changing the width of progress bar and then make next() function
**slider.component.ts**

```
  next() {
    console.log(this.slickModal) // gives first modal
    console.log(this.eventsModal) // gives undefined
    this.slickModal.slickNext();
  }
```

Here is an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'slickNext' of undefined

Can someone help to fix this ? How should I use 2 `<ngx-slick-carousel>` on same page/file ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my html of 2nd slider wasn't correct ,two slliders can work . As I understand after `ngx-slick-carousel` the child should have `ngxSlickItem`

```
<div *ngIf="eventsSlider">
<div class="events-slider">
    <div class="events-slider__arrows news-arrows active-arrows"></div>
    <div class="events-slider__arrows activity-arrows"></div>
    <div class="events__tabs">
        <div class="title tab news-tab active">
            news
        </div>
        <div class="switch first-on">
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="title tab activity-tab">
            events
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="events__tab-content">
        <div class="news-item tab-item active-tab">
            <div class="news-slider">
                <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #eventsModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig">
                    <a ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let banner of eventsBanners" href="#" class="events__item">
                        <div class="events__item-image">
                            <img src="assets/img/{{ banner.img }}.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="events__item-wrapper">
                            <div class="date-view">
                                <div class="date-view__date">
                                    <img src="images/icons/calendar.svg" alt="">{{banner.date}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="date-view__view">
                                    <img src="images/icons/eye.svg" alt="">{{banner.views}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="events__item-title">
                            {{banner.title}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="events__item-text">
                            {{banner.description}}
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </ngx-slick-carousel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPD 1**

But I still cant handle next() function. Function changes my first slick, but also gives an error that it cant slickNext() of undefined . He still thinkgs that he should make slickNext() to both modals , even if I separate them in the beginig.

```
next() {
    this.mainBanner.slickNext(); 
 }

  @ViewChild('slickModal') mainBanner: SlickCarouselComponent;
  @ViewChild('eventsModal') eventsModal: SlickCarouselComponent;
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'slickNext' of undefined